# Bug na acentuação fora das tags

Tags: bug, status-pronto, acentuação, interface-usuário

Parece que os acentos foram colocados nas tags do site principal. mas ainda há algum problema dos nomes das tags fora delas. Provavelmente está gravando algo errado no DB. Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aproveitando, acho que devemos começar trocar as tags para as acentuadas. Acho que é o certo a fazer, apesar de alguns inconvenientes que serão gerados. Se alguém for contra, deixe um comentário aqui. Vou esperar um pouco antes de começar mudar.

Comment: Acho que são poucas tags (só as com cedilha), não vejo problema em fazer agora, e posso colaborar. Só não podemos esquecer de mover também os wikis, pois acho que de madrugada roda um script que apaga tags sem perguntas, aí os wikis iriam embora junto.

Comment: @bfavaretto e outros, em http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/443/precisamos-de-padronizacao-para-tags-com-mais-de-uma-palavra tem vários pontos relevantes para decidirmos definitivamente o que fazer com as tags. Vamos aproveitar para arrumar tudo.

Comment: O Marc Gravell confirmou que o site principal já está ok.

Comment: To be clear: this was not a DB issue - it was purely a UI (double-encoding) glitch (Traduz Google diz: Para ser claro: isto não era um problema de DB - era puramente uma falha UI (double-encoding).)

Comment: @MarcGravell I suspected so. Off-topic: Google Translate did a good job on translating your comment, but funnily enough it failed to correctly translate "Google Translate"!

Comment: @MarcGravell I just found a [very similar issue](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/448) in the close as duplicate dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed in the next deploy; thanks for reporting this.

---

Será corrigido no próximo ciclo de atualização. Obrigado por reportar.