# Duplo encoding no resultado de busca por duplicatas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, acentuação, interface-usuário

No diálogo de fechar pergunta como duplicata, se o corpo da pergunta inclui tags formatadas como `[tag:nome-da-tag]`, se a tag contiver acentos, e se ela aparecer no excerto da pergunta exibido no diálogo, vemos códigos de entidades HTML em vez dos caracteres acentuados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parece [outro](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/442) problema de duplo encoding. Isso não ocorre nos resultados de busca comuns, fora desse diálogo.

Comment: I will investigate tomorrow

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks, and please let me know if you need additional details; I can add them in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvido no build rev `2014.1.15.1855` do meta e `2014.1.15.1304` dos sites.

> Fixed in build rev `2014.1.15.1855` on meta and `2014.1.15.1304` on sites.

Comment: Thanks m0sa! Since we are here, do you know if any dev is taking care of [this other bug](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/78)? It's really annoying for reviewers, and we'd be really thankful if someone fixed it (it appears to be a simple CSS bug). Thanks again!