# Bug ao marcar pergunta como duplicata

Tags: bug

Quando clicamos em "Isso resolveu o meu problema" aparece o alert com a mensagem, mas está mal formatada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu bug se refere ao `&#225`? Se for isso é relacionado ao [encoding do a com acento agudo](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html) que é o correspondente `&#225`. [...] Isto marcar**á** [...]

Comment: A um certo tempo atrás também ocorreu https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/448/66203 , https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/442/66203

Comment: Problemas no "port" para tradução, afinal somos o primeiro site da rede SE que não usa inglês. Na verdade se vocês olharem o source do HTML verão que todos acentos são "entidades", penso eu pessoalmente que isso já poderia ter sido resolvido na codificação baseada em UTF-8 diretamente na conexão com o banco, mas claro que provavelmente seja complicado pois talvez todos sites da rede use "entidades", então o melhor talvez seria modificar o alert para um alert customizado, ou resolver no JavaScript quando for usar modais (alert/confirm, etc).