# Erro ao editar perguntas na versão mobile

Tags: bug, status-aceito, mobile

Ao editar perguntas que tenham tags com acentuação na versão mobile do site as tags não são reconhecidas e aparecem mal-formatadas. Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso, tive que apagar as tags e reescrever antes de salvar a edição.

Utilizo Chrome no Android 7.

Comment: Provavelmente é o mesmo problema que este https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6345/3635, o site usa entidades ao invés de unicode, apesar que na versão desktop muita coisa foi melhorada, ainda sim são problemas do "port" para português, afinal somos o primeiro site da rede a usar "acentos" ou melhor caracteres além dos do "inglês tradicional".

Comment: O que significa esse "status-aceito"? O bug continua, acabei de testar. Não entendi.